# Nodes are not opening up properly after executing the runnodes script

Tags: corda

I was exploring thIS cordapp example
https://github.com/corda/corda-training-template.git

There is a total of 4 nodes (Notary, A, B, and C) in this example. I am trying to open all the nodes in a single run using runnodes script from the terminal.

But all the nodes are not opening at a time. It's like alternatively they are opening, onetime only Notary and C nodes are opening and another time A and B nodes are opening.
Any specific reason?
And also I am getting this message in the webserver terminal. Please explain.
"The Corda specific webserver is deprecated and will be removed in future".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The runnodes script is not a very reliable way of starting up the nodes. Its mostly used for development purposes to make development faster.

It might sometimes not work as expected.  The script works by opening up a terminal window and running the command to start the node in that particular terminal. Depending on the speed of the system, the command sometimes gets executed before the new terminal is opened up.

The reliable way to start a Corda node, however, is to use the `java -jar corda.jar` command. So just go into each individual nodes folder and run the command to start the node.

Here's the script :

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

set -eo pipefail

# Allow the script to be run from outside the nodes directory.
basedir=$( dirname "$0" )
cd "$basedir"

if [ -z "$JAVA_HOME" ] && which osascript >/dev/null; then
    # use default version of java installed on mac
    /usr/libexec/java_home --exec java -jar runnodes.jar "$@"
else
    "${JAVA_HOME:+$JAVA_HOME/bin/}java" -jar runnodes.jar "$@"
fi
```

Its the same one that you use to start the node, found in `build/nodes` folder

Comment: Thanks, Ashutosh, it's working fine as per your instruction. Could you please tell me where to find this runnodes script in the project?

Comment: Updated in the answer